# Invalid unicode in url, можно ли передать файл в другой кодировке в URL?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib, tornado

На сервере есть два вида файлов utf-8, к которым я могу получить доступ без проблем и файлы KOI8-R, к которым я не могу получить доступ.

Важно указать, что это изображения и кодировки отличаются в названии.
`3D%20Bone%20Vegan%2005%200820%201.jpg` конечный урл utf-8, все окей
имя файла koi8-r: 'Старый университет.jpg'

Пробую `urllib.parse.quote('Старый университет.jpg', encoding="KOI8-R")`, на что мне любезно прилетает 400 ошибка со словами: `Invalid unicode in url: b'\xf3\xd4\xc1\xd2\xd9\xca \xd5\xce\xc9\xd7\xc5\xd2\xd3\xc9\xd4\xc5\xd4.jpg'`

Возможно я что-то делаю не правильно, буду очень признателен за информацию.

p.s

Если пробовать без encoding, то бросает 404, хотя файл этот я в консоли вижу.

Comment: `Invalid unicode in url` - так от вас `unicode` ждут, т.е. `UTF-8`

Comment: Вопрос исчерпан, удалось найти спецификацию, которая отражает, что данные должны быть UTF-8, ответ @CrazyElf, так же полезен.

Comment: Тогда оформлю прямо как ответ. Вдруг кому будет полезно )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Invalid unicode in url
        ^^^^^^^
```

Судя по ошибке, сервер ждёт от вас кодировку `unicode`, т.е. скорее всего `UTF-8` (но бывают и другие кодировки `unicode`).